# When using like in SQL query getting accurate result but not when using match & against

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a table having 400 000+ data and I need to implement the search in it.

The table structure:

- Table name: foods
- 193 Columns
- Implement search in short_food_description column (This column is already indexed)

I have created a node API for fetching the data

```
app.get('/foods', (req, res) => {
  const searchTerm = req.query.term;
  const pageNumber = req.query.page || 1;
  const limit = 20;
  const offset = (pageNumber - 1) * limit;

  let sql = `SELECT id, food_database, food_id, keylist, food_description, short_food_description 
               FROM foods`;

  if (searchTerm) {
    const sanitizedSearchTerm = db.escape(`%${searchTerm}%`); // Escaping and enclosing searchTerm with % for LIKE clause

    sql += ` WHERE short_food_description LIKE ${sanitizedSearchTerm}`;
  }

  sql += ` LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset}`;

  console.log('Generated SQL query:', sql);

  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Database query error:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: 'Internal server error'
      });
    }
    res.json(results);
  });
});
```

When i search "banana strawberry" this return accurate results but when i use this

```
app.get('/foods', (req, res) => {
  const searchTerm = req.query.term;
  const pageNumber = req.query.page || 1;
  const limit = 20;
  const offset = (pageNumber - 1) * limit;

  let sql = `SELECT id, food_database, food_id, keylist, food_description, short_food_description 
               FROM foods`;

  if (searchTerm) {
    const sanitizedSearchTerm = db.escape(searchTerm);

    // Check if the search term contains boolean characters
    const hasBooleanCharacters = /[+\-><\(\)~*\"@]/.test(searchTerm);

    if (hasBooleanCharacters) {
      sql += ` WHERE MATCH(short_food_description) AGAINST(${sanitizedSearchTerm} IN BOOLEAN MODE)`;
    } else {
      sql += ` WHERE MATCH(short_food_description) AGAINST(${sanitizedSearchTerm} IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`;
    }
  }

  sql += ` LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset}`;

  console.log('Generated SQL query:', sql);

  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Database query error:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: 'Internal server error'
      });
    }
    res.json(results);
  });
});
```

This return "strawberry banana" first
The like query is taking long time and not give accurate result on other search terms.
Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you're trying to implement a full-text search functionality in your Node.js API using MySQL. However, there are a few things that might be causing issues with your implementation:

**Boolean Mode vs. Natural Language Mode:** Depending on your specific requirements, you may need to adjust the search mode. Boolean mode allows for more complex search queries with boolean operators, while natural language mode is generally more user-friendly but may have limitations in handling certain types of searches.

**Query Performance:** Full-text searches can be resource-intensive, especially on large datasets. It's essential to ensure that your database server is properly configured for full-text search operations and that the indexes are optimized for the type of queries you're executing.

**Query Syntax:** The syntax for full-text search queries in MySQL can be tricky, especially when dealing with boolean mode. Make sure that your search terms are properly escaped and formatted according to MySQL syntax rules.

**Indexing:** While you mentioned that the short_food_description column is already indexed, it's crucial to ensure that the index is optimized for full-text search queries. In MySQL, you typically use a FULLTEXT index for columns used in full-text searches.

Here are a few suggestions to improve your implementation:

1. Check your MySQL server configuration to ensure that full-text search functionality is enabled and properly configured.
2. Review the MySQL documentation on full-text search to ensure that you're using the correct syntax for your queries.
3. Consider experimenting with different search modes (BOOLEAN MODE, NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) to see which one best suits your requirements.
4. Analyze the performance of your queries using MySQL's EXPLAIN statement to identify any potential bottlenecks or optimization opportunities.
5. Make sure that your short_food_description column is properly indexed using a FULLTEXT index.

By addressing these points and possibly adjusting your implementation accordingly, you should be able to improve the accuracy and performance of your full-text search functionality in the Node.js API.
Let's address the issues in your code:

**Sanitizing Search Term:** In the first implementation, you correctly sanitized the search term for the LIKE clause, but in the second implementation using full-text search, you're using db.escape() which might not be appropriate for full-text search queries. Instead, you should use it only for string literals to prevent SQL injection.

**Full-Text Search Syntax:** When using full-text search in MySQL, you need to ensure that the search term is properly formatted and enclosed in single quotes if it's a string literal. You also need to handle special characters and boolean operators appropriately.

**Indexing:** While you mentioned that the short_food_description column is indexed, it's essential to ensure that it's indexed correctly for full-text search. In MySQL, you need to use a FULLTEXT index for columns used in full-text searches.

Here's how you can correct your code:

```
app.get('/foods', (req, res) => {
  const searchTerm = req.query.term;
  const pageNumber = req.query.page || 1;
  const limit = 20;
  const offset = (pageNumber - 1) * limit;

  let sql = `SELECT id, food_database, food_id, keylist, food_description, short_food_description 
             FROM foods`;

  if (searchTerm) {
    // Escape the search term only if you're using it as a string literal
    const sanitizedSearchTerm = db.escape(searchTerm);

    // Check if the search term contains boolean characters
    const hasBooleanCharacters = /[+\-><\(\)~*\"@]/.test(searchTerm);

    if (hasBooleanCharacters) {
      // Enclose the search term in single quotes and handle special characters
      sql += ` WHERE MATCH(short_food_description) AGAINST('${sanitizedSearchTerm}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`;
    } else {
      // Enclose the search term in single quotes for NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
      sql += ` WHERE MATCH(short_food_description) AGAINST('${sanitizedSearchTerm}' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`;
    }
  }

  sql += ` LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset}`;

  console.log('Generated SQL query:', sql);

  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Database query error:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: 'Internal server error'
      });
    }
    res.json(results);
  });
});
```

With these corrections, your full-text search functionality should work correctly, and you should get accurate results based on the search terms provided. Ensure that your short_food_description column is properly indexed for full-text search to optimize the query performance.

Comment: Please do not use GenAI generated content as an answer!